# Why loading image inside an Iframe from parent as FileContentResult failed?

Tags: jquery, iframe, model-view-controller, filecontentresult

I have a file upload inside an Iframe. when a user upload an image this file upload send the image to the server and server pass the file name to the file upload. Now I use this name and send it to an action that gives me image file as `FileContentResult`. See below:

```
.on('fileuploaddone', 
     function (e, data) {
     name = data.result.files[0].name;
     if (name) {
         var el = $('<div class="imageLayer" onClick="ShowTopTools(this)">'+
                 '<div class="resizePan"></div>'+
                 '</div>');
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = '/Advertisement/Image/'+name;
         image.onload = function () {
                  el.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')')
                    .css('width', this.width)
                    .css('height', this.height);
         }          
         $("#box").append(el);
});
```

Every things work fine until `image.onload` fired. It runs the function but at the close bracket; It was failed. 
background-image of el get this: `Background-image: url(undefined);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your problem reason is **asynchronicity**, so try this code:

```
.on('fileuploaddone', 
     function (e, data) {
     name = data.result.files[0].name;
     if (name) {
         var el = $('<div class="imageLayer" onClick="ShowTopTools(this)">'+
                 '<div class="resizePan"></div>'+
                 '</div>');
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = '/Advertisement/Image/'+name;
         $(image).data('target',e.target.result);
         image.onload = function () {
                  el.css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data('target') + ')')
                    .css('width', this.width)
                    .css('height', this.height);
         }          
         $("#box").append(el);
});
```